# error with text document connecting to my countdown calendar

Tags: python, windows, countdown

Hello dear people of the internet, lately I have been working on a code that with the help of a text document will tell you the amount of days left until the date in the text document. It worked at first but lately there has been syntax error when I run it, I've only started coding a few months ago so I don't exactly understand the syntax errors.

this is the code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas
from datetime import date, datetime
def get_events():
    list_events = []
    with open ('events.txt') as file:
        for line in file:
            line = line.rstrip('\n')
            current_event = line.split(',')
            event_date = datetime.strptime(current_event[1], '%d/%m/%y').date()
            current_event[1] = event_date
            list_events.append(current_event)
    return list_events
def days_between_dates(date1, date2):
    time_between = str(date1 - date2)
    number_of_days = time_between.split(' ')
    return number_of_days[0]

root = Tk()

c = Canvas(root, width=800, height=800, bg='black')
c.pack()
c.create_text(100, 50, anchor='w', fill='orange', font='ComicsansMS 32 bold underline', text='My countdown calendar')

events = get_events()
today = date.today()

vertical_space = 100

for event in events:
    event_name = event[0]
    days_until = days_between_dates(event[1], today)
    display = 'it is %s days until %s' % (days_until, event_name)
    c.create_text(100, 100, anchor='w', fill='lightblue', font='Arial 28 bold', text=display)

    vertical_space = vertical_space + 30
```

I think that this is a problem in the text document, I've tried making new ones and replacing the old one, but the error still appears.
this is the current .txt document:
my birthday,20/03/23

thank you people of the internet in advance :)

Comment: FYI, if you get an error, post the full error in your question.

Comment: also, adding a `root.mainloop()` and running it, your code runs fine. It's 127 days to your birthday...

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).